# How to apply wildcard in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I would like to read csv with query

Now I have csv file below

```
A  B C
K1 1 7
K2 2 8
K3 3 9
L1 4 10
L2 5 11
L3 6 12
```

I would like to read csv and get result below

```
A B  C
K1 1 7
K2 2 8 
K3 3 9
```

I tried

```
pd.read_csv(file).query("A=='K*'")
```

But it dint work well.
How can I extract the rows which contains K?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df[df.A.str.startswith('K')]
```

Comment: How would I adjust a conditional like this to look for anything that contains UN:   data.loc[(data["Fmt"] != str) & (data["Format"] == "UN*"), "Format"] = 'BD'

Comment: @pes04: `df.A.str.contains("UN")`.